# Problema ao fazer um update

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, hibernate, autenticação, spring-security

Bem estou tento dificuldade para realizar um update em meu banco de dados ele esta apresentando a seguinte exception.

> > ERROR
> >     [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter]
> >     (default task-11) An internal error occurred while trying to
> >     authenticate the user.:
> >     org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException:
> >     Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value
> >     mapping was incorrect) : [br.com.netservicos.sic.model.Folha#61]    at
> >     org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:127)
> >         at
> >     org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:144)
> >         at
> >     org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
> >         at
> >     org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199)
> >         at
> >     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
> >         at
> >     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218)
> >         at
> >     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> >         at
> >     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
> >         at
> >     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> >         at
> >     org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124)
> >         at
> >     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> >         at
> >     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> >         at
> >     org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
> >         at
> >     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> >         at
> >     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> >         at
> >     org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
> >         at
> >     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> >         at
> >     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> >         at
> >     org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:106)
> >         at
> >     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> >         at
> >     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
> >         at
> >     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
> >         at
> >     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
> >         at
> >     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
> >         at
> >     org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> >         at
> >     org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
> >         at
> >     io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
> >         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
> >         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
> >         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
> >     javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Row was updated or deleted
> >     by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) :
> >     [br.com.netservicos.sic.model.Folha#61]     at
> >     org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.wrapStaleStateException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1714)
> >         at
> >     org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1634)
> >         at
> >     org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
> >         at
> >     org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608)
> >         at
> >     org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1171)
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> >     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
> >     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
> >     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
> >     org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344)
> >         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy56.merge(Unknown Source)     at
> >     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)     at
> >     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
> >     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
> >     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
> >     org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:294)
> >         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy56.merge(Unknown Source)     at
> >     br.com.netservicos.sic.dao.FolhaDAOImpl.update(FolhaDAOImpl.java:48)
> >         at
> >     br.com.netservicos.sic.service.authenticatioin.UserDetailService.loadUserByUsername(UserDetailService.java:95)
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> >     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
> >     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
> >     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
> >     org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
> >         at
> >     org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
> >         at
> >     org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
> >         at
> >     org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
> >         at
> >     org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
> >         at
> >     org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
> >         at
> >     org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
> >         at
> >     org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
> >         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.loadUserByUsername(Unknown Source)    at
> >     org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:115)
> >         ... 63 more Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row
> >     was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value
> >     mapping was incorrect) : [br.com.netservicos.sic.model.Folha#61]    at
> >     org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:322)
> >         at
> >     org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:170)
> >         at
> >     org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:69)
> >         at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:840)
> >         at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:822)   at
> >     org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:827)  at
> >     org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerIm
>
> pl.java:1161)     ... 91 more

o metodo que esta sendo usado para realizar a autenticação é esse.

```
@Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {

        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(login)) {

            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Não foi possível localizar o Usuário");
        }

        Optional<Usuario> optional = usuarioService.findByLogin(login);

        if (!optional.isPresent()) {

            LOGGER.error("Não foi possível localizar o login: {}", login);

            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Não foi possível localizar o Usuário.");
        }

        Usuario usuario = optional.get();

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = usuarioService.carregarPerfil(usuario.getPerfil());

        Principal principal = new Principal(usuario.getId(), usuario.getNome(), usuario.getSobrenome(), usuario.getLogin(), usuario.getEmail(),
                usuario.getPerfil().getNome(), usuario.getSenha(), usuario.getSituacao(), authorities);

        LocalDate data = LocalDate.now();
        LocalTime entrada = LocalTime.now();
        LocalTime saidaAlmoco = LocalTime.now();
        LocalTime voltaAlmoco = LocalTime.now();
        LocalTime saida = LocalTime.now();


        List<Folha> findDateUser = folhaService.findByDateAndUser(data, usuario.getId());


        if(findDateUser.size() == 0){

            Folha folha = new  Folha();

            folha.setData(data);
            folha.setUsuario(usuario);
            folhaDAO.persistir(folha);
        } else if(findDateUser.size() != 0){

            Folha folhaEntrada = new Folha();

            long idFolha = 0;

            idFolha = findDateUser.iterator().next().getIdFolha();
            folhaEntrada.setIdFolha(idFolha);
            folhaEntrada.setData(data);
            folhaEntrada.setUsuario(usuario);
            folhaEntrada.setEntrada(entrada);


            folhaDAO.update(folhaEntrada);
        }


        return principal;

    }

}
```

o problema está no momento em que pego o id da entidade folha espero que possam me ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom consegui resolver o problema, o erro estava em não setar o version fiz isso e o problema foi solucionado.